# Import .msg format email information (including Subject, Sender, CC, Receiver, SentDate, etc) to excel cells

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook

I am a newbie of *VBA*. I would be appreciate if anyone could kindly provide a Excel or Outlook VBA script for My task.

The task in relatively simple. I have more than 4000 .msg format files (outlook emails) in a folder. I would like to extract certain email informations *(Subject, Sender, CC, Receiver, SentDate)* and import these informations to excel cells, like:

```
Subject  Sender   CC     Receiver    SentTime   SentDate

Re:..     Mike   Jane    Tom     12:00:00    23 Jan 2013
```

The only way I can think of is open these *.msg files* one by one and copy and paste these information to excel. Obviously, this is not realistic given the huge quantity of files.

I have seen some relevant VBA scripts on stackflow but not exactly what I want.

Comment: `I would be appreciate if anyone could kindly provide a Excel or Outlook VBA script for My task.` Welcome to stackoverflow Andy. :) Unfortunately it doesn't work like this here. You will have to help yourself. Show us the code that you tried and the error message that you are getting and we will then help you correct it?

Comment: Check out my answer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16074387/extract-outlook-message-body-text-with-vba-from-excel/) question, should give you what you're looking for. HTH,
Z

Answer (score 2):

You can either use the Outlook Object Model and its `Namespace.OpenSharedItem` method or you can use Redemption (I am its author) and its `RDOSession.GetMessageFromMsgFile` method:

```
set Session = CreateObject("Redemption.RDOSession")
set Msg = Session.GetMessageFromMsgFile("c:\temp\temp.msg")
MsgBox Msg.Subject
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there are some open source programs that can read .MSG files, not only Outlook:

- http://redeye.hoffer.cx/detail.php?id=13
- http://auxilii.com/msgparser/

Choose one message and try to export the fields you want to some better format like CSV, and once you have that, it should be easy to apply that to all the messages in batch with any scripting language